# How to use external functions in Vue Component data binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm js newbie, I want to use external functions in vue component data bindings but it fails to work

helper.js

```
function groupArrayOfObjects(list, key) {  
    return blah blah
}

function parseDate(d) {      
    return bla bla
}

export { groupArrayOfObjects, parseDate };
```

vue component:

Vue warn]: Property or method "parseDate" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

```
 <template>
          <div>{{parseDate(date) }}</div>  
    </template>

    import { groupArrayOfObjects, parseDate } from "@/assets/js/helper.js";
    export default {
        methods:{
          abc(){ groupArrayOfObjects(param1, param2);}
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to spread the helper functions inside the methods option :

```
import * as helpers from "@/assets/js/helper.js";

export default {
  methods: {
    abc() { groupArrayOfObjects(param1, param2); },
    ...helpers
   
  }
}
```

in template :

```
 <template>
   <div>{{parseDate(date) }}</div>  
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use imported functions in your `template`, as they are not really part of the component. If you want to use those imported functions you need to add them to your components `method` object. Similar to what you already did with your `groupArrayOfObjects` function.

```js
import { groupArrayOfObjects, parseDate } from "@/assets/js/helper.js";

export default {
  methods: {
    abc() { groupArrayOfObjects(param1, param2); },
    
    // either wrap your function
    foo(date) { parseDate(date) },
    
    // or just add it directly
    parseDate,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `parseDate` function from helper and expose this function for the template.

```
 <template>
  <div>{{ parseDate(date) }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { parseDate } as helpers from "@/assets/js/helper.js";

export default {
  methods: {
    parseDate
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this *might* be a valid solution you should include some explanation about why it works and how it solves the problem. Don't forget to quote and link to any relevant documentation.